# Javascript - Extract numbers from string

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable that will change, but always be in the following format:

- var treasure = "3rd Audience discussion (10 min.) for 300 people"
- var treasure = "4th Talk (2 min.) for 250 people"
- var treasure = "7th Demonstration (8 min.) for 800 people"

And I want to get hold of the number which is inside the parenthesis with "min."

i.e. in the above 3 examples...

- 10
- 2
- 8

How do I get these numbers?

Comment: it could be accomplish with a regex

Comment: Maybe with a regex, see the example i made on regexr :
regexr.com/4vqkc

Comment: Thanks for the help!
So far I have treasure.text(\(([0-9]*)+.*\); but it's not working for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do something like:

```js
function getMinutes(str){
  return +str.replace(/^.*\((\d+).*\).*$/, '$1');
}
console.log(getMinutes('3rd Audience discussion (10 min.) for 300 people'));
console.log(getMinutes('4th Talk (2 min.) for 250 people'));
console.log(getMinutes('7th Demonstration (8 min.) for 800 people'));
```